# Stellar.js not working as expected on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, stellar.js

I have a site which uses `Stellar.js` for it's parallax effect. It works as expected in the desktop versions, however on tablets (unsure if it's just iOS) the parallax effect doesn't work.

I have got no idea why... Below is the code I am using to initialize `Stellar.js`:

```
include('js/stellar/jquery.stellar.js');
$(window).load(function() { 
  if ($('html').hasClass('desktop')) {
      $.stellar({
        horizontalScrolling: false,
        verticalOffset: -50
      });
  }  
});
```

Comment: parallax effect(if you're talking about background image scrolling) doesn't work in ipad. (its a bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Bhojodendra Nepal, there is a bug that stops stellar.js functioning on iPad.